# Load certain information from array index obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist

I have an array that loads information from a plist like so:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"items.plist"];
```

Here is how the plist looks like:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>string</key>
    <string>STR</string>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>0</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>string</key>
    <string>STR2</string>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>string</key>
    <string>STR3</string>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>2</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>string</key>
    <string>STR4</string>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>35</string>
    <key>data</key>
    <string>5</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

I have also created a for-loop that creates a UIButton for every string there is in the plist, how do I check in the loop if the index contain a 'data' key?
I would like to check if the index has data so I can set an image to the button.

Comment: Show the code you tried so far and explain what it does wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"items.plist"];
for (NSDictionary * dict in array) {
    UIButton * newBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [newBtn setTitle:dict[@"id"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // -- Update for comment -- //
    // See if data exists
    if (dict[@"data"]) {
        // if data's value is an image ...
        [newBtn setImage:dict[@"data"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // In your question the values for @"data" are integers, so make sure you don't try to add that as an image.

    }

    // do other stuff with button ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I also check if the same index has the key 'data' then use that value to set the image for the button?

Comment: @Mike - I added a way to do that.  Although, in your question, the value for data is '5' so I don't think it's an image.  Adjust accordingly.

Comment: I have images preset according to their string and data so my image would be "STR45.png" :) Thanks so much it worked!

Comment: Glad you got it working, good luck with the rest of your project!